# Contents of Checked List Box not showing in .copyfromscreen method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a print function that invokes the graphics.copyfromscreen method to take a screen shot then uses the print page event to print said screenshot. Everything is working fine for all of the controls except the contents of the Checked list box are not displaying on print Any help with getting them to show on print would be appreciated.

Here is the code for the .copyfromscreen method.

```
Private Sub CaptureScreen()
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Dim s As Size = Me.Size
    MemoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics)
    Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(MemoryImage)
    For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctl) Is Button Then
            ctl.Visible = False
        End If
    Next ctl
    Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, s)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
    For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctl) Is Button Then
            ctl.Visible = True
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of CopyFromScreen(), consider switching to [DrawToBitmap()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Idle_Mind : You were 4 minutes faster ;) (writing from my phone).

Comment: Thank you @Idle_Mind this change worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of taking a literal screenshot of the form, use the [**`Control.DrawToBitmap()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it draw itself onto a bitmap. It should show the contents of the `CheckedListBox` as well as it forces it to be drawn onto the bitmap like if it were a regular form.

```
'Hide all buttons.
For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
    btn.Visible = False
Next

'Dispose of the old bitmap to release memory.
If MemoryImage IsNot Nothing Then MemoryImage.Dispose()

MemoryImage = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
Me.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, Me.Size))

'Show all buttons.
For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
    btn.Visible = True
Next
```

Comment: @Tom : Glad I (and Idle_Mind) could help! Good luck!